# Why is this program to check prime numbers not working?

Tags: c

I just started programming. I wrote a simple C program for checking prime numbers but its not working.  Please help me out finding my mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int n,i,c=0;
   printf("enter any number: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   for(i=2;i<n;i++)
   {
     if(n%i==0)
       c=c+1;
     if(c>0){
       break;
       printf("\n%d is  not   a prime number",n);
     }
   }
   if(i==n)
     printf("\n%d is a prime number",n);
}
```

Comment: Does your compiler not emit a warning for the statement after `break;`?

Comment: Not sure why it isn't working, but c seems like a useless variable here.  Why not just do: if(n%i==0)
   { stuff in here }

Answer (score 1):

If you put `break` after `printf("\n%d is  not   a prime number",n);` the program works correctly. When C executes `break` command it immediately jumps off the closest loop, so it does not execute the next line in the loop, i.e. does not print that it is not a prime number.

Comment: ...But it would be better if the output lines ended with newlines, and `c` really isn't needed, and there should be more use of spaces within lines of code and less random spacing in strings used in output, and the standard supports `int main()` rather than `void main()`, and the algorithm isn't very efficient...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed all is true that you wrote! He is a beginner so he will learn these things. I just tried to resolve why the program is not working correctly, which was his question. Other things are more about style and efficiency of the program.

Comment: Yeah, and that's fine (it is OK to limit the scope of your answer); it's why I made a comment rather than forcing my information into an answer.